# Why the proof of closure under addition in Linear Map is $(T+S)(u+v)$ instead of $(T+S)(u)$ and $(T)(u+v)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading *Linear Algebra Done Right* and want to prove that $L(V, W)$ is a vector space. I have read the solution here:

[image]
Why the proof of closure under addition in Linear Map is $(T+S)(u+v)$ instead of $(T+S)(u)$ and $(T)(u+v)$?

I am very confused on when we do the sum in functions, and when we do the sum in vectors.

Comment: You're gonna have to show us an example of what you're talking about, maybe cite the proof in question or link us

Comment: @D_S is it better now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your questions should come from carefully using all the definitions.  What does it mean for a function $\phi: V \rightarrow W$ to be linear?  It means that

$$\phi(u+v) = \phi(u) + \phi(v)$$

$$\phi(c v) = c \phi(v)$$

for all $u, v \in V$ and scalars $c$.  So in the proof, they are checking that $\phi = T + S$ is linear.

The definition of $T+S$ is it's the function which sends $v \in V$ to $Tv + Sv$ in $W$.